# Is there a way for maven script to automatically download dependent jars of dependencies i specify in a pom

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

Is there a way for maven script to automatically download dependent jars of dependencies i specify in a pom ?

For example i specify the following in my pom.xml ,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

i want a tool that resolves any dependencies that the "spring-core" depends on and update the pom as well as downloaded dependencies.
Any ide's / build plugins that do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yes you can download from MAVEN Central repository by specifying central repository location in your maven home. ie .m2/settings.xml

<mirror>
       <id>mirrors.dotsrc.org</id>
       <name>Mirror of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</name>
       <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
       <mirrorOf>central2</mirrorOf>
</mirror>

and in your pom add following..
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>

Please refer.
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.springframework%22
```

Comment: will this automatically download the jars Spring depends on ?